# ifstream and oftream issue

Tags: c++, stream, filestream

Just this:

```
int size = getFileSize(path); //Listed below
ifstream fs(path, ios::in);
ofstream os(path2, ios::out);

//Check - both streams are valid
char buff[CHUNK_SIZE]; //512

while (size > CHUNK_SIZE)
{   
    fs >> buff;
    os << buff;
    size -= CHUNK_SIZE;
}
char* dataLast = new char[size];
fs>>dataLast;
os<<dataLast;
fs.close();
os.close();
```

//Found on SO, works fine

```
int getFileSize(string path)
{
FILE *pFile = NULL;

if (fopen_s( &pFile, path.c_str(), "rb" ))
{
    return 0;
}

fseek( pFile, 0, SEEK_END );
int Size = ftell( pFile );
fclose( pFile );
return Size;
}
```

File at path2 is corrupted and less then 1 Kb. (initial file is 30Kb);
I don't need advices how to copy file, I am curios what is wrong about this example.

Comment: No advices, but reading using `>>` is what not you're thinking right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First an **important** warning: **Never** (as in really never) use the formatted input operator for `char*` **without** setting the `width()`! You open yourself up to a buffer overrun. This is basically the C++ version of writing `gets()` which was bad enough to be removed (not just deprecated) from the C standard! If you insist in using formatted input with `char*` (normally you are much better off using `std::string`), set the width, e.g.:

```
char buffer[512];
in >> std::setw(sizeof(buffer) >> buffer;
```

OK, with this out of the way: it seems you actually want to change two important things:

1. You probably don't want to use formatted input, i.e., `operator>>()`: the formatted input operators start off with skipping whitespace. When reading into `char*` it also stops when reaching a whitespace (or when the `width()` is non-zero when having read a much characters and still space to store a terminating zero; note that the set `width()` will be reset to `0` after each of these reads). That is you probably want to use unformatted input, e.g., `in.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer))` which sets `in.gcount()` to the number of characters actually read which may be less then size parameter, e.g., at the end of the stream.
2. You probably should open the file in `std::ios_base::binary` mode. Although it doesn't matter on some systems (e.g., POSIX systems) on some systems reading in text mode merges a line end sequence, e.g. `\r\n` on Windows, into the line end character `\n`. Likewise, when writing a `\n` in text mode, it will be replaced by a line end sequence on some system, i.e., you probably also want to open the output stream in text mode.

Answer (score 1):

Th input and output operators, when used with strings (like `buff` is from the libraries point of view), reads space-delimited words, only.

If you want to read chunks, then use [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read), and use [`std::istream::gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to get the number of bytes actually read. Then write with [`std::ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

And if the data in the file is binary, you should use the [`binary` open mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).